# sed and grep: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, macos, unix, sed, grep

I'm trying to build a project. When I execute a bash script it shows me this error:

```
Harshits-MacBook-Air:build harshitprasad$ . bin/thisroot.sh
sed: -e expression #1, char 47: unterminated `s' command
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: sed: No such file or directory
-bash: root-config: command not found
-bash: grep: command not found
-bash: grep: command not found
```

Here is the code:

```
drop_from_path()
{
   # Assert that we got enough arguments
   if test $# -ne 2 ; then
      echo "drop_from_path: needs 2 arguments"
      return 1
   fi

   local p=$1
   local drop=$2

   newpath=`echo $p | sed -e "s;:${drop}:;:;g" \
                          -e "s;:${drop}\$;;g"   \
                          -e "s;^${drop}:;;g"   \
                          -e "s;^${drop}\$;;g"`
}

if [ -n "${ROOTSYS}" ] ; then
   old_rootsys=${ROOTSYS}
fi

SOURCE=${BASH_ARGV[0]}
if [ "x$SOURCE" = "x" ]; then
    SOURCE=${(%):-%N} # for zsh
fi

if [ "x${SOURCE}" = "x" ]; then
    if [ -f bin/thisroot.sh ]; then
        ROOTSYS="$PWD"; export ROOTSYS
    elif [ -f ./thisroot.sh ]; then
        ROOTSYS=$(cd ..  > /dev/null; pwd); export ROOTSYS
    else
        echo ERROR: must "cd where/root/is" before calling ". bin/thisroot.sh" for this version of bash!
        ROOTSYS=; export ROOTSYS
        return 1
    fi
else
    # get param to "."
    thisroot=$(dirname ${SOURCE})
    ROOTSYS=$(cd ${thisroot}/.. > /dev/null;pwd); export ROOTSYS
fi

if [ -n "${old_rootsys}" ] ; then
   if [ -n "${PATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$PATH" "${old_rootsys}/bin"
      PATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "${old_rootsys}/lib"
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH" "${old_rootsys}/lib"
      DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${SHLIB_PATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$SHLIB_PATH" "${old_rootsys}/lib"
      SHLIB_PATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${LIBPATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$LIBPATH" "${old_rootsys}/lib"
      LIBPATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${PYTHONPATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$PYTHONPATH" "${old_rootsys}/lib"
      PYTHONPATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${MANPATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$MANPATH" "${old_rootsys}/man"
      MANPATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH" "${old_rootsys}"
      CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$newpath
   fi
   if [ -n "${JUPYTER_PATH}" ]; then
      drop_from_path "$JUPYTER_PATH" "${old_rootsys}/etc/notebook"
      JUPYTER_PATH=$newpath
   fi

fi

if [ -z "${MANPATH}" ]; then
   # Grab the default man path before setting the path to avoid duplicates
   if `which manpath > /dev/null 2>&1` ; then
      default_manpath=`manpath`
   else
      default_manpath=`man -w 2> /dev/null`
   fi
fi

if [ -z "${PATH}" ]; then
   PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin; export PATH
else
   PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin:$PATH; export PATH
fi

if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH       # Linux, ELF HP-UX
else
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi

if [ -z "${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ]; then
   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib; export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH   # Mac OS X
else
   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH; export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi

if [ -z "${SHLIB_PATH}" ]; then
   SHLIB_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib; export SHLIB_PATH                 # legacy HP-UX
else
   SHLIB_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$SHLIB_PATH; export SHLIB_PATH
fi

if [ -z "${LIBPATH}" ]; then
   LIBPATH=$ROOTSYS/lib; export LIBPATH                       # AIX
else
   LIBPATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$LIBPATH; export LIBPATH
fi

if [ -z "${PYTHONPATH}" ]; then
   PYTHONPATH=$ROOTSYS/lib; export PYTHONPATH
else
   PYTHONPATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$PYTHONPATH; export PYTHONPATH
fi

if [ -z "${MANPATH}" ]; then
   MANPATH=$ROOTSYS/man:${default_manpath}; export MANPATH
else
   MANPATH=$ROOTSYS/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
fi

if [ -z "${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" ]; then
   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$ROOTSYS; export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH       # Linux, ELF HP-UX
else
   CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$ROOTSYS:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH; export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
fi

if [ -z "${JUPYTER_PATH}" ]; then
   JUPYTER_PATH=$ROOTSYS/etc/notebook; export JUPYTER_PATH       # Linux, ELF HP-UX
else
   JUPYTER_PATH=$ROOTSYS/etc/notebook:$JUPYTER_PATH; export JUPYTER_PATH
fi

if [ "x`root-config --arch | grep -v win32gcc | grep -i win32`" != "x" ]; then
  ROOTSYS="`cygpath -w $ROOTSYS`"
fi

unset old_rootsys
unset thisroot
unset -f drop_from_path
```

Output of the `env` command:

```
Harshits-MacBook-Air:build harshitprasad$ env
rvm_bin_path=/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/bin
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
GEM_HOME=/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
IRBRC=/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/.irbrc
TMPDIR=/var/folders/c7/b45s17816zn_b1dh3g7yzxrm0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.2va6DsChFN/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=400
OLDPWD=/Users/harshitprasad/Desktop/gsoc/root
MY_RUBY_HOME=/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2
TERM_SESSION_ID=6A7C8CB1-C291-4A18-BD1F-0090F62984A8
USER=harshitprasad
_system_type=Darwin
rvm_path=/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.fsBTexrYJp/Listeners
rvm_prefix=/Users/harshitprasad
PATH=/anaconda3/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/bin
PWD=/Users/harshitprasad/Desktop/gsoc/root/build
_system_arch=x86_64
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
_system_version=10.13
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
rvm_version=1.29.3 (latest)
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/harshitprasad
LOGNAME=harshitprasad
GEM_PATH=/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.mLrbJ4Ww3r/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.4.2
_system_name=OSX
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Output of `echo $PATH` in the terminal:

```
 Harshits-MacBook-Air:~ harshitprasad$ echo $PATH
/anaconda3/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/harshitprasad/.rvm/bin
```

`sed` and `grep` installation check:

```
Harshits-MacBook-Air:~ harshitprasad$ which sed
/usr/local/bin/sed
Harshits-MacBook-Air:~ harshitprasad$ which -a grep
/usr/bin/grep
```

I have checked and it looks like sed and grep are already installed. I have also installed Xcode v9.2 and working machine is macOS v10.13. I'm thinking this situation can be solved by defining PATH environment variable.

How should I solve the above issue? How should I setup environment variables? It would be great if anyone can help me out! Thank you :)

Comment: Include your code.  What is your `PATH` set to?

Comment: @codeforester Now I have added code of `thisroot.sh` to my question. Please have a look. Thank you. :)

Comment: @John1024 shared the code in the question. :)

Comment: What is `$ROOTSYS`? It seems to be causing the first call to `sed` to fail, which sets `newpath` to the empty string, which then gets copied to `PATH`... and since that's what tells the system where to find executables, once that happens it can't find any commands (except shell builtins).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Actually, this file gets created whenever I build the project. This is the project: https://github.com/root-project/root . What should be solution then?

Comment: @HarshitPrasad I don't see the primary cause of the problem in that script. What is `$ROOTSYS` before you run the script? Also, try running `set -x` just before running the script, so it'll print commands as it executes them, then add the output of that through the first `sed` command and a couple of lines after that (if I'm right, it'll have `+ newpath=` followed by `+ PATH=`).

Comment: BTW, while I don't see the cause of this specific problem in the script itself, it's full of dubious scripting practices.

Comment: As @GordonDavisson says, the coding style of that script is dubious at best. I see years and years of patches over patches: ROOT is a very old project and binary packages are available for a number of platforms, so that the building system is much less tested than it should be, as long as it works on the machines of a few package maintainers... My guess: a strnage character in your `$PATH` breaks the awfully written `sed` command... could you post the output of `echo $PATH` ??

Comment: Better still: the output ofthe command `env` ?

Comment: @Dario Thank you for giving time to my question :) I have pasted the output of the command `env`.

Comment: Apart from a directory containing a `@` in your `PATH` (which might break the building process somewhere else) there is nothing suspect in your environment... Can you edit the script and place `echo "drop is $drop"` just after the line `local drop=$2`, and post the output?

Answer (score 2):

From the error messages, somewhere in that script, you're calling `drop_from_path` with something that has a `;` in the second argument.  That causes the sed command to become malformed, giving the first error you see AND setting the resulting `newpath` to empty.  Since you then set `PATH=$newpath` without checking it, this clears the PATH, resulting in all further non-builtin commands failing (all the other errors you see).

Comment: Yes, and there is more: the subsequent `-e`-arguments of `sed` are interpreted as filenames, which obviously don’t exist, and generate the _No such file or directory_ errors.